# Is there a way to install imagick in wordpress. I have no access to ssh and php.ini file. It's shared hosting. Can it be done via .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, imagick, adsapi-php.ini

I am unable to install the imagick module via cpanel. I am on shared hosting and have no access to the ssh and php.ini. Is there a way to configure this with htaccess file. I'd really appreciate any assistance. I've been looking online for the past 24hrs and nothing

I have tried using  php.ini and ssh but these have failed as I have no access as mentioned above

Comment: Please ask your provider for help. This is not a programming issue, and not related to Wordpress or [tag:adsapi-php.ini]

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response but my provider says it's an issue I need to diagnose

Comment: And "unable to" means what, exactly? Are you getting any error message when you try to do so, or - what?

Answer (score 0):

connect with provider for that because it is impossible with .htaccess

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).